# SSH: Permission denied as given IdentityFile is not used

Tags: ssh, openssh, certificates

I'm using this .ssh/config:

```
Host myserver
    HostName 12.34.67.89
    User anyuser
    IdentityFile /root/.ssh/anything_rsa
```

But running `ssh myserver` returns a `Permission denied (publickey)` error.

Why isn't the given identity file (`root/.ssh/anything_rsa`) be used? Instead it seems to use `/root/.ssh/id_rsa`

```
OpenSSH_7.0p1, OpenSSL 1.0.1r  28 Jan 2016
debug1: Connecting to myserver [12.34.67.89] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: permanently_set_uid: 0/0
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.0
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to myserver:22 as 'admin'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com <implicit> none
debug1: kex: client->server chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com <implicit> none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: XXXXX
debug1: Host 'myserver' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /root/.ssh/known_hosts:4
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /root/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

Running `ssh -v -i /root/.ssh/anything_rsa -l anyuser myserver` is working. So it seems the config file is not used properly... I don't understand that at all...

Comment: Can you please edit your question to show the output of `ls -l /root/.ssh`?  Does it work if you manually specify the IdentityFile?  `ssh -i /root/.ssh/anything_rsa myserver`

Comment: @JimL. It returns `lrwxrwxrwx    1 admin    administ        15 Dec  5 20:49 /root/.ssh -> /etc/config/ssh/`

Comment: Try removing the symlink and creating a proper .ssh directory, chmod it 700, and populate it with your keys.

Comment: @JimL. I've updated the post. If I use the path and the username directly in the command, everything is working fine, but using the config file doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The comments below your post indicate that `/root/.ssh` is a symlink to another directory.  I have never had a reason to use a symlinked .ssh directory, but I'm fairly certain that ssh will entirely ignore an .ssh directory that is either not owned by the user in question, or is group- or world-readable.  IOW, it must be `chown root` and `chmod 0700` for ownership and permissions.  My hunch is that the target directory (`/etc/config/ssh`) of your symlink either is not owned by root, or is not 0700, and so ssh is ignoring your config file and using the default IdentityFile name of id_rsa.

Update: your comments below this post indicate that, although you are referencing an `IdentityFile` in root's .ssh directory, you are not actually running as root.  The section below has been edited to reflect your username of `admin`.

For purposes of troubleshooting, consider trying:

```
cd ~admin
mkdir .ssh
chmod 700 .ssh
cp -RLp /etc/config/ssh/* .ssh
chown -R admin .ssh
```

Then try again.

Comment: I'm running all this on a QNAP NAS server. And there the ssh directory is set by default this way. I did not change anything here. the `/etc/config/ssh/` directory has `drw-------    2 admin    administ`

Comment: There you go.  Wrong owner.  Also probably should be drwx instead of drw.  All the more reason to create a REAL .ssh directory instead of a symlink to a directory that's owned by the wrong user.

Comment: But running `whoami` gives me `admin`. So the owner should be correct, right?

Comment: If you're admin, why are you expecting to use the config file in root's .ssh directory?  Have you tried putting your config file (and keys) in `~admin/.ssh`? Also, why no 'x' in the perms of `/etc/config/ssh`?  Try `chmod u+x /etc/config/ssh`

Answer (score 2):

You need to set `IdentitiesOnly yes` in your `~/.ssh/config` (or global `/etc/ssh/ssh_config`), otherwise all other available identities are also tried.

With `IdentitiesOnly yes` only the identities defined with `IdentityFile` (and certificates defined with `CertificateFile`) will be used (if not passed on the command-line).

```
Host myserver
    HostName 12.34.67.89
    User anyuser
    IdentitiesOnly yes
    IdentityFile /root/.ssh/anything_rsa
```

Comment: I haven't had to use the IdentitiesOnly directive in my .ssh/config. I upvoted because this is the most cogent explanation I've read for how this directive works.

Answer (score 0):

If somebody came to this thread like I am because of trying to establish SSH from QNAP NAS to linux machine, here is the answer:

In my case I generated `id_rsa` on NAS from `admin` (`/share/homes/admin/.ssh/id_rsa`) which is default `sudo` there.  And I try to connect to linux host with the command

```
ssh root@hostname
```

which returned an error. But

```
ssh -i /share/homes/admin/.ssh/id_rsa root@hostname
```

works.

So to connect to root user on remote host you don't need to generate a new key from admin you need to use key pair which are already presented in `/root/.ssh/` on NAS. Or generate a new pair there.